# Transparent Data Encryption in Magento 2.3 Database

Tags: magento2, security

I need to encrypt customer data (company name, contact person, emai, address, etc.) within the magento mysql database.

I'd like to realize this without introducing encryption/decryption in every module where customer data is used. I think of a solution similar to the transparent data encryption (TDE) known from oracle.

How could I realize a transparent data encryption for the magento 2 database? If this is not possible what would be the best alternatives?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?